# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, cv2.HoughLinesP function

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv3.0

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if img is None:
        break
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 120)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, math.pi/1, 20, None, 2, 480);

    dot1 = (lines[0][0][0],lines[0][0][1])
    dot2 = (lines[0][0][2],lines[0][0][3])
    cv2.line(img, dot1, dot2, (255,0,0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("output", img)
    length = lines[0][0][1] - lines[0][0][3]
    print (length)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

I'm getting an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hari/Downloads/New folder/liquid.py", line 17, in <module>
    dot1 = (lines[0][0][0],lines[0][0][1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Yup, you can **not** do `None[0]`..

Comment: it seams `lines` is `None` - as I know if CV functions have some problem then they never raise error but return `None` - so you have to check returned value.

Comment: Yes, you are right lines was none.Thanks for the help.